# logical operator that returns operands in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, logical-operators, idioms

In any "sane" programming language, from C to Javascript, an expression such as `a || b` (or `a or b`) evaluates to `a` if `a` is true and to `b` otherwise, making possible things like `a = params.a || default_a` and similar for the `and` operator, but PHP begs to differ.

**Is there any way to get this in PHP? Or is there any "coding idiom/pattern" that PHP programmers use instead of something like the code below?**

```
$a = $my_a || $default_a; // nope, $a gets a boolean
```

Because writing `if ($my_a) $a = $my_a; else $a = $default_a;` or `$a = $my_a ? $my_a : $default_a;` seems very ugly to me and violates basic "DRY-ness" of code by making me repeat something like `$my_a`, which can also be a very long and complicated expression.

It's a minor thing, I know, and not that singular in the land of the [double clawed hammer](http://www.flickr.com/photos/raindrift/7095238893/in/set-72157629492908038/) but it really annoys the hell outta me!

Comment: Are you simply ranting about php? Logical operators work in php like they do anywhere else. Better yet, just use a ternary operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @MikeS. I really didn't know about the "default" behavior of the ternary operator explained in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worth to mention: It's C and Javascript, that makes the difference, because "in a 'sane' language" (;)) the return value of a boolean operation is a boolean and not one of its operands.

However

```
$a = $my_a ?: $default_a;
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Comment: Still there are many current servers with 5.2.x it's worth mentioning that only 5.3 allows this.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Then you should change your hoster. It's 2012. PHP5.2 is not maintained anymore, 5.3 is out for 3 years now and even 5.4 is out. It's time...

Comment: @MihaiStancu kudos for the version gotcha, although KingCrunch is right

Comment: He is right but for small scale web projects where the client already has a hosting provider and/ or has payed upfront for a year of hosting services it'll be tricky to explain why he has to change hosting providers.

Comment: It's really not worth changing hosting providers over a _single line of code_. It'll take way more time to make the switch than it will to just expand that line a bit.

Comment: @David Seems, that you don't know, what changed with 5.3. It's not only "a single line of code". Additional (I cannot mention it often enough): _No security fixes for 5.2 anymore! Never again!_ I didn't even said, that you should use 5.4, just 5.3. 3 years old. And so on...

Comment: @KingCrunch I'm referring simply to the issue raised in this question: if PHP 5.2 works fine for the poster _except_ this issue, why bother changing hosts? Believe me, I refuse to use anything earlier than 5.3 because I use namespaces and closures extensively.